Share only second screen with a freelancer with remote control
I am currently working with an external freelancer for some time.
Right now, we are working on a sub-project. For security reasons, I can't share him login username/password, so he has to work through remote control for now.
Here is what I need:

Remote control to one monitor or one window (monitor is preferred, but Chrome window is also okay).

I also use my PC for my personal work, so he shouldn't be able to see the other monitor for my privacy.

View-only is not enough. He needs to be able to control his screen. And I should control my screen.



Even if you share only one screen, how would both of you work simultaneously? How would being bound to one screen stop him from accessing any data on your computer?

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Risk of accessing sensitive data is not a problem because I will be working on the other screen and keeping an eye on him. But you are right about the mouse/keyboard problem. In the end, I decided to install anydesk on a VirtualBox instance.

I decided to install a new OS on a VirtualBox instance.
It has a shared folder with a host PC for sharing a folder.
I disabled the shared clipboard for security reasons.
Afterwards, I installed Chrome remote support on VirtualBox instance.
It solved the problem

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
